# Escaping a space in a properties file for WildFly with Oracle DB

Tags: linux, oracle, jdbc, wildfly

I am having a hard time using an environment variable with a space in a properties file read by WildFly (24) in Linux using Oracle 19 in RDS.  One like:

`SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`

The issue is that wildfly won't even parse the file if the spaces are in there with the normal quoting methods.

I have it setup so that variable is in a file called datasource.properties that gets read from standalone.conf where this variable sits:

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DDATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK=${DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK}"`

It's read in with the following in standalone.conf:

```
set -a
. /opt/wildfly_config/datasource.properties
set +a
```

That in turn gets populated in standalone.xml with:

`<connection-url>${env.DATABASE_JDBC_URL}</connection-url>`

I try putting it in quotes and oddly enough it doesn’t start at all.  Standalone.sh is no longer able to parse it:

`Error: Could not find or load main class 1 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1`

I have tried many things such as:

```
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="SELECT{ }1{ }FROM{ }DUAL"
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="'SELECT 1 FROM DUAL'"
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK='SELECT 1 FROM DUAL'
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="SELECT+1+FROM+DUAL"
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="SELECT\ 1\ FROM\ DUAL"
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="\"SELECT 1 FROM DUAL\""
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="\"'SELECT 1 FROM DUAL'\""
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="SELECT%201%20FROM%20DUAL"
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="SELECT\{ }1\{ }FROM\{ }DUAL"
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK='SELECT{ }1{ }FROM{ }DUAL'
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="'SELECT{ }1{ }FROM{ }DUAL'"
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="''SELECT{ }1{ }FROM{ }DUAL''"
DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="SELECT%1%FROM%DUAL"
```

(I realize some of these don't make sense but I was looking for anything different.)
Startup looks good in the log output this with some of these, but then java doesn’t like it, for some reason it sees the escape usage:

`Caused by: Error : 936, Position : 9, Sql = SELECT+1+FROM+DUAL, OriginalSql = SELECT+1+FROM+DUAL, Error Msg = ORA-00936: missing expression`

or

`Caused by: Error : 911, Position : 6, Sql = SELECT%1%FROM%DUAL, OriginalSql = SELECT%1%FROM%DUAL, Error Msg = ORA-00911: invalid character`

or

`WARN  [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) IJ030027: Destroying connection that is not valid, due to the following exception: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@2c1456f8: java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 7`

This last one is the only one that really netted anything different. I got that with:
`DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="SELECT{}1{}FROM{}DUAL"`

I can use sed to change the value in the standalone.xml, but all of the other properties I am doing work fine with the exception of this one.  I had a hard time with a semicolon in the jdbc string with MSSQL and putting the semicolon in braces like "{;}" fixed that.  This DB apparently does not follow the same syntax.

Is there an encoding type that will help this with Oracle and keeps wildfly happy?

EDIT:  More tests:

`DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK=\"SELECT' '1' 'FROM' 'DUAL\"`

gets

`Caused by: Error : 900, Position : 0, Sql = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL", OriginalSql = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL", Error Msg = ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement'`

(doesn't seem to like the quotes)

But without the escaping of the quotes I get:

`Caused by: Error : 923, Position : 9, Sql = SELECT' '1' 'FROM' 'DUAL, OriginalSql = SELECT' '1' 'FROM' 'DUAL, Error Msg = ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution was to change the sourcing of the file from:

```
set +a
. /opt/PrimeKey/wildfly_config/datasource.properties
set -a
```

to

```
. /opt/PrimeKey/wildfly_config/datasource.properties
```

and make it so all the variables brought in were variables and not properties:

```
export DATABASE_CONNECTION_CHECK="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
```